# Git local changes are inadvertently applied across all branches

Tags: git

I have two local branches that are both remotely tracked upstream.

Let's call the first branch "A" and the second branch "B". I checkout branch A and make a local change to a file. I expect that when I switch over and checkout branch B the local changes I've done in branch A will not carry over to branch B. Why does it carry over in this case?

Even in the cases where I'll add a new file to be committed in branch A, and then checkout branch B, that same file is added to the list of files to be committed.

Comment: Show us the process you use. Are you actually `committing` the changes to branch `a`?

Comment: I'm not committing the changes -- my mental model of how it worked was that any local changes done to the current branch checked out should stay isolated in that particular branch. When switching to other branches, it shouldn't carry over those local changes.

Comment: Ah, that's not how it works. You need to either commit or stash the changes before switching to another branch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Local changes will continue to exist until you either commit the changes or stash them. This is nice since you might be working on something which you then decide you'd prefer to commit to a different branch (e.g. a feature branch, or staging).

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response - but this still doesn't seem intuitive to me. Let's say I'm working on two features in parallel. Feature A should stay isolated in branch A and feature B should stay isolated in branch B. Are you saying that I would have to stash/commit everytime I switch back and forth between branches?

Comment: Yes. A great thing about git is how cheap commits and branches are. You can make a commit which is your ongoing work on a branch, then go back to it later and amend the commit with further work, or do an interactive rebase (https://help.github.com/articles/interactive-rebase). In order for git to keep track of work in a specific branch which you want gone from your current working directory, it needs a commit. That's the mechanism.

Comment: It also helps a lot when you are on some branch (`master` or `feature` or whatever) and you start coding a bit, and then realize: hmm, wait, this is too complex to just shove it in here.  What you can do at this point is `git checkout -b experiment`, commit code on the new `experiment` branch now, experiment more, commit more, and then—*after* you've figured out how it should go into `feature` or `master`—go back to the original branch and start putting in the "real version".

Answer (score 1):

Your uncommitted changes are, well, un-committed. Which means they are not committed to anything, therefore they are not part of your active branch. The only way you can link your changes to the current branch is to stash them.

However, I never leave any changes in the air, I like to commit them and only after that I change branches.